# Button Group how to change count of JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hello anybody know how to made ButtonGroup like only 5 of 10 options could be selected ? 
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will have to programmatically code this check using selection events.